# Encrypt and decrypt by parts do not seem to work

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptojs

Consider the code:

```
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f");
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f");

// encrypt
var aesEncryptor = CryptoJS.algo.AES.createEncryptor(key, { iv: iv });

var ciphertextPart1 = aesEncryptor.process("Message Part 1");
var ciphertextPart2 = aesEncryptor.process("Message Part 2");
var ciphertextPart3 = aesEncryptor.process("Message Part 3");
var ciphertextPart4 = aesEncryptor.finalize();

// decrypt
var aesDecryptor = CryptoJS.algo.AES.createDecryptor(key, { iv: iv });

var plaintextPart1 = aesDecryptor.process(ciphertextPart1);
var plaintextPart2 = aesDecryptor.process(ciphertextPart2);
var plaintextPart3 = aesDecryptor.process(ciphertextPart3);
var plaintextPart4 = aesDecryptor.process(ciphertextPart4);
var plaintextPart5 = aesDecryptor.finalize();

console.log(plaintextPart5.toString());
```

Source: https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#ciphers

Maybe I am wrong, but **I expected the messages to be decrypted**.

The output is actually:

```
61676520506172742033
```

I have no idea what that output means and where that comes from.

If I print out another part, the same issue:

```
console.log(plaintextPart4.toString());
```

Output:

```
7373616765205061727420324d657373
```

**Discussion**

One comment says that I am wrong on my assumption regarding how the method works, a nice answer could nicely correct me as well! I know the difference, from my studies, between one-way encryption and by parts: it makes no sense to me the way it is actually working, it seems a bug. My ideia is that you could keep adding message to be encrypted, as we can do with hashing, in the case of hashing (from the same abovementioned source), it seems to work, why not for encryption as well?

Comment: You're ignoring all the other plaintexts.

Comment: what do you mean? I have printed them, the same problem!

Comment: That looks like the hex encoding of an ASCII string. Perhaps the `.toString()` method on that object outputs in hex.

Comment: An possible solution?

Comment: I have tried something like `.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)`, but it does not accept as in hashing.

Comment: The point is, you **don't** want hex output, so try something like `toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)`.

Comment: worked partially: `age Part 3`. There is not age at the message!

Comment: I have done several tests with this solution and the outputs are mad, something like 2 for a long message.

Comment: `aesEncryptor.process` flushes all blocks except the last block. This block is only flushed by `process` when it is completely filled. Otherwise it is flushed by finalize (also adds the padding). `aesDecryptor.process` flushes all blocks except the last block. This is flushed by `finalize` (also removes the padding).

Comment: Hey there @Topaco, thanks for your comment. How does that solve my problem?

Comment: _Maybe I am wrong, but I expected the messages to be decrypted._ I'm afraid yes, you're wrong. The plaintext is the _concatenation_ of all plaintexts (`plaintextPart1`,...,`plaintextPart5`). The `finalize` methode _generally_ returns only a fraction. The same applies to encryption. `process` and `finalize` are intended for _successive_ encryption/decryption. If you need encryption/decryption in _one_ step, there are the `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt` and `CryptoJS.AES.decrypt` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I honestly expected this example to work since it is from the official documentation, and they do not mention anything.

Comprehensive documentation is a rare beast.

> it makes no sense to me the way it is actually working, it seems a bug

It works like this:

```js
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

const original_message = " ...0, ...1, ...2, ...3, ...4, ...5, ...6, ...7, ...8, ...9, ...The End!"

var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f");
var iv  = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f");

const aesEncryptor = CryptoJS.algo.AES.createEncryptor(key, { iv: iv });
const aesDecryptor = CryptoJS.algo.AES.createDecryptor(key, { iv: iv });

const fragment_size = 25
const e_acc = []
for(let i = 0 ; i*fragment_size < original_message.length ; ++i ) {
  const slice = original_message.slice(i*fragment_size, i*fragment_size + fragment_size)
  console.log("slice to encrypt", slice)
  e_acc.push(aesEncryptor.process(slice));
}
e_acc.push(aesEncryptor.finalize());

let message = ""
for(let i = 0 ; i !== e_acc.length ; ++i ) {
  message += aesDecryptor.process(e_acc[i]).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)
  console.log("intermidiate message", message) 
}
message += aesDecryptor.finalize().toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)
console.log("full message", message)
```

> [...] it supposes to be a trick that you can add information by parts
>   [...]
>   My idea is that you could keep adding message to be encrypted

And you can, the only thing is - you can't decipher parts of messages that do not fill a block. You can only get as much as fits into a chain of **complete** blocks.

Consider the code

```
const sum1 = solver.process("1+22+3")
const sum2 = solver.process("03")
const sum3 = solver.finalize()
```

Here you can get the **intermediate** `sum1` - sum of `1` and `22`. But you can't add `3` right away, because, as you can see later on, it is not actually `3` but `303`. Same thing with `sum2` - `solver` do not know yet if the `303` should be added or maybe it would become `3031234...`. So the only thing the `solver` can do is to remember the `3` and then the `303`, but not use it. Until you call `finalize`.

`aesEncryptor` is like the `solver` but much more complicated.

Let's get back to the `aesDecryptor` and why all of `plaintextPart*` contain only the parts of the message... Why do you need "Progressive Ciphering" in the first place? Probably because you are sending fragments over the net? The key word is **fragments** - they purposely do not contain all the previous parts of the message as they could weight gigabytes!

> in the case of hashing [...], it seems to work, why not for encryption as well?

Hashing is a quite different thing. You can not expect that AES has all the same properties as hashing, as you can not expect that hashing has all the same properties as, for example, summation.

Comment: Thanks, quite nice answer! I will keep the bounty still opened for a while. Thanks for all the clarification!

Comment: Glad, It helped. By the way, the codesandbox I've posted somehow worked but then suddenly stopped - `require` fails. Did it work for you?

Comment: I did not try yet!

Comment: Well, I've already removed it for good. But if you'd care to try, the link is in the history of edits

Comment: I was going to try now. Does that mean that your answer is no longer valid? I would appreciate to see a code.

Comment: It's valid. Just try it out in your environment. But don't know about codesandbox. My connection is really poor and I can't spend much more time awating for codesandbox to load.

Comment: It is working, nonetheless, it seems you changed the initial proposal. You are breaking the message into pieces, and then make the encryption.

Comment: in that case, what I had in mind does not work. I tought of being able to add something later. What you are doing one can do with one-way encryption.

Comment: It bothers me that we need to do all this work you are doing, and added to the fact that I have seen some stranger behaviors, as you have also pointed out, regarding the size of the encryption block.

Comment: On nice thing you did is that it solves the problem of the block sizes, I can add "hi" in the end and it comes out properly!

Comment: Also, you solved the problem of small blocks, I can just say "hi" and it saves, and decrypt!

Comment: And what is your purpose? But any way, just don't call `finalize` and your can keep adding and reading chunks of messages. But there is **no way** you can add/send/save a smaller than a block-size message without `finalize`

Comment: I have no purpose. I was studying, and found this problem, and I tought this could help somebody else. Tthis site helped me a lot, and I want to keep the flow!

Comment: OK. Keep it up!  :)

Answer (score 1):

The `.process` method returns any new chunks of ciphertext that were generated by processing the plaintext given as the argument to `.process` along with any plaintext that was left over from earlier encryptor activity.

In this case the cipher algorithm is AES.  Specifically it's AES-128, because the key used to create the encryptor is 128 bits long.  AES-128 consumes plaintext in 128-bit (16-byte) blocks and emits 128 bits (16 bytes) of ciphertext for each plaintext block.  This block-based processing is what produces the results that you didn't understand.

What happens with your program is:

```
var ciphertextPart1 = aesEncryptor.process("Message Part 1");
```

The encryptor is given 14 bytes of input.  That's not enough to allow it to generate a ciphertext block, so `.process` returns an empty ciphertext result which you store in `ciphertextPart1`.  The encryptor stores the unprocessed 14 bytes internally.

```
var ciphertextPart2 = aesEncryptor.process("Message Part 2");
```

This gives the encryptor a further 14 bytes.  It appends those to the 14 bytes left over from the previous call, so it now has a total of 28 unprocessed bytes.  It processes as many of those bytes as it can.  That is, it processes the first 16 of those bytes ("Message Part1Me") and returns the ciphertext block for those 16 bytes, which you store in `cipherText2`.  The encryptor now contains 12 unprocessed bytes.

```
var ciphertextPart3 = aesEncryptor.process("Message Part 3");
```

This gives the encryptor another 14 bytes.  It now has 26 unprocessed bytes.  It processes the first 16 of those bytes ("ssage Part2Mess") and returns the ciphertext block for those 16 bytes, which you store in `cipherText3`.  The encryptor now contains 10 unprocessed bytes.

```
var ciphertextPart4 = aesEncryptor.finalize();
```

This forces the encryptor to process any unprocessed bytes.  It can only work on 16-byte blocks, so it adds 6 bytes of padding to the remaining 10 unprocessed plaintext bytes ("age Part 3"), encrypts that block and returns the ciphertext for that block.  You store that ciphertext block as `ciphertextPart4`.

And now you decrypt the ciphertext blocks.

```
var plaintextPart1 = aesDecryptor.process(ciphertextPart1);
```

`cipherTextPart1` was an empty block, so `plaintextPart1` will be empty and obviously the decryptor will retain no unprocessed ciphertext.

```
var plaintextPart2 = aesDecryptor.process(ciphertextPart2);
```

`cipherTextPart2` contained the encrypted version of the first 16 bytes of the plaintext, so `plaintextPart2` will contain "Message Part 1Me".  The ciphertext input was exactly 16 bytes long, therefore the decryptor contains no unprocessed ciphertext.

```
var plaintextPart3 = aesDecryptor.process(ciphertextPart3);
```

`cipherTextPart3` contained the encrypted version of the next 16 bytes of the plaintext, so `plaintextPart3` will contain "ssage Part 2Mess".  Again the decryptor is holding no unprocessed ciphertext.

```
var plaintextPart4 = aesDecryptor.process(ciphertextPart4);
```

`cipherTextPart4` contained the encrypted version of the final 10 bytes of the plaintext, so `plaintextPart3` will contain "age Part 3".  No unprocessed ciphertext remains in the decryptor.

```
var plaintextPart5 = aesDecryptor.finalize();
```

The is no unprocessed ciphertext remaining in the decryptor, so `finalize` has no work to do and `plaintextPart5` will be empty.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your answer. It was quite explicative. Still the question: **how does that solve my problem?** I honestly expected this example to work since it is from the official documentation, and they do not mention anything.

Comment: If I understood properly, your point is: **the message should be bigger**. Tested! same problem! Now I can see part of the message, but it is not practical if part of the message disappears.

Comment: I have tested your assumption "That's not enough to allow it to generate a ciphertext block". It worked, but.... it eats part of the text, the final part. I have used for text 1: "1. My name is Jorge Guerra Pires; 2. My name is Jorge Guerra Pires; 3. My name is Jorge Guerra Pires; 4. My name is Jorge Guerra Pires", and printed: "My name is Jorge Guerra Pires; 2. My name is Jorge Guerra Pires; 3. My name is Jorge Guerra Pires; 4. My name" If I add garbage in the end: "fffffffffffffffffffffffff", it comes out all the text, but… also part of the garbage.

Comment: The final ciphertext is still problematic (the output is meaningless), it supposes to be the sum of all parts, if I understood properly, it supposes to be a trick that you can add information by parts.